# CGAL build with CMake fail silent on Windows VS2019

Tags: cgal, cmake-gui

I've been trying to build CGAL with cmake_gui by following 
https://doc.cgal.org/latest/Manual/windows.html#title8
and
http://acg.cs.tau.ac.il/cgal-at-tau/installing-cgal-and-related-programs-on-windows

except with CGAL5.0.2 and QT5 and boost 1.72. I did also cmake_gui the ZLIB 1.2.11 ok.

the issue is that after configuring, there is no code generated or any error message. the Generated CGAL.sln only contains housekeeping projects without the lib projects.

i did have to manually edit the boost lib location and qt location until there is no unresolved symbols from the cmake gui. the boost, gmp and fpmr libs are present and they show up in the gui groups but they do not show up in the generated solution. the console output from the cmake_gui during the configure phase is very short.. but no error. see below.

== Setting paths ==

Build CGAL from release in directory CGAL-5.0.2

Packagenames: CGAL-5.0.2

== Setting paths (DONE) ==

== Generate version files ==

CGAL_MAJOR_VERSION=5

CGAL_MINOR_VERSION=0

CGAL_BUGFIX_VERSION=2

CGAL_SONAME_VERSION=13

CGAL_SOVERSION     =13.0.3

CGAL_REFERENCE_CACHE_DIR=

Building shared libraries

Visual Leak Detector (VLD) is not found.

Targetting Visual Studio 16 2019

Target build enviroment supports auto-linking

Using VC toolset 142.

Generator uses intermediate configuration directory: $(Configuration)

USING CMake version: 3.17.1

System: Windows

== Generate version files (DONE) ==

Multi-configuration CMake generator: cannot display flags

== Detect external libraries ==

== Detect external libraries (DONE) ==

== Generating build files ==

Configuring libCGAL

Boost include dirs: E:/dev

Boost libraries:

USING GMP_VERSION = '5.0.1'

USING MPFR_VERSION = '3.0.0'

USING BOOST_VERSION = '1.72.0'

libCGAL is configured

Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Core' detected

Configuring libCGAL_Core

libCGAL_Core is configured

Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_ImageIO' detected

Configuring libCGAL_ImageIO

USING ZLIB_VERSION = '1.2.11'

libCGAL_ImageIO is configured

Sources for CGAL component library 'CGAL_Qt5' detected

Configuring libCGAL_Qt5

USING Qt5_VERSION = '5.12.4'

libCGAL_Qt5 is configured

Sources for CGAL component libraries 'CGAL_Core;CGAL_ImageIO;CGAL_Qt5' detected

== Generating build files (DONE) ==

Configuring done
Generating done

[cmake_gui after config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/umQiS.png)
[VS19 sln view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D6YRo.png)

any hint would be helpful.

thanks

Comment: CGAL is header-only now, there is no lib to build. Did you try building an example?

Comment: Marc, the original issue i encountered was that when i received a vc project that is missing CGAL_Qt5-vc142-mt-gd-5.0.lib during linking. i traced it back to having to rebuild the cgal using with qt5 and vc142 so i followed a few tutorials and comments (http://acg.cs.tau.ac.il/cgal-at-tau/installing-cgal-and-related-programs-on-windows, notice step 5 last line). or, see the pictures in this post: https://www.twblogs.net/a/5b8e0aff2b71771883427813 .. i don't find many reference of using such cgal lib in the official cgal manual except partially in the part 3 of the manual.

Comment: All your links are for old versions of CGAL, before it became header-only.